# What is the name for proofs with (without) Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, terminology, axiom-of-choice

In many contexts we distinguish between proofs using AC and proofs which do not use AC. (To phrase this somewhat differently: If there is a proof without AC, this proof is usually preferred.)

I would like to know whether there are names commonly used for these two types of proofs.

In my mother tongue I have heard the names which could be translated to English as *effective-proof* (for the proof avoiding AC) and *non-effective proof* or *ineffective proof* (for the proofs employing AC).

When I searched for these term on internet
[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22axiom+of+choice%22+%22effective+proof%22),
[2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22axiom+of+choice%22+%22non+effective+proof%22),
[3](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22axiom+of+choice%22+%22ineffective+proof%22)
and in Google Books
[1](https://books.google.com/books?q=%22axiom+of+choice%22+%22effective+proof%22),
[2](https://books.google.com/books?q=%22axiom+of+choice%22+%22non+effective+proof%22),
[3](https://books.google.com/books?q=%22axiom+of+choice%22+%22ineffective+proof%22), I found some hits. But not enough to be persuaded that these two terms are widely used.

So I would like to ask

> - Can some of the names for the proofs with/without AC which I mentioned above considered standard?
> - Are other names for such proofs commonly used?

Comment: Without AC: 'constructive'. With AC: 'non-constructive' if it's actually referred to.

Comment: I had the feeling that the phrase [constructive proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof) is often used in different meaning. Wikipedia article I linked mentions [famous example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118810/an-easy-example-of-a-non-constructive-proof-without-an-obvious-fix/1118851#1118851) of with $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}$ and $(\sqrt2^{\sqrt2})^{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Or the proof of existence of transcendental number based on cardinality argument, although this proof [can be made constructive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_uncountability_proof#Constructive_or_non-constructive_nature_of_Cantor.27s_proof_of_the_existence_of_transcendentals) if we are more careful.

Comment: I've not run into a pair of terms that could reliably be interpreted that way. *Constructive* doesn't work, because it frequently excludes much more than just $\mathsf{AC}$, and neither does *effective*. (I'm curious about your first sentence, though: the only context in which I find any need to make the distinction is that of specifically investigating consequences of $\mathsf{AC}$ and its variants. In any other context I consider its use utterly unremarkable.)

Comment: Same as Brian. I don't know a "correct" term. I usually just write "choice free" or "in ZF" or "the axiom of choice is not needed".

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What I meant was that at least some authors often indicate whether the proof uses AC or not. But I will admit that I have mostly seen this in texts related to set theory. But basically for any results from any area it seems reasonable to ask whether AC was used. (I have heard some such questions asked, for example, in talks about topics from algebra and real analysis.) In any case, I rephrased the first paragraph a bit.

Comment: @mistermarko "Constructive proof" is different concept with the "proof without AC". König's lemma is provable in ZF without AC, but it is considered to nonconstructive.

Comment: @tetori: You need to be careful when saying that König's lemma is provable without choice. It is true if one adds the assumption that the tree is countable, but if one phrases it in a general way "Every tree of height $\omega$, with finite levels has an infinite branch" then the axiom of choice is needed.

Comment: I quite like the terms "choiceless" for proofs that avoid AC (which suggests the complementary "choiceful" for proofs using AC)

Comment: Why put a bounty? As mentioned in the comments there is no standard term.

Comment: I vote for "Choicefuln't"

Comment: @ℋolo: I think "mostly not-non-constructive proofs" is even better.

Comment: @AsafKaragila unfortunately I believe that "mostly constructive proofs" is a bit of a confusing name.

Comment: "Why put a bounty? As mentioned in the comments there is no standard term." But that was 6 years ago.. and clearly an update/refresh was appropriate here; btw +1 Martin