# Prove or disprove that there is a rational number $x$ and an irrational number $y$ such that $x^y$ is irrational

Tags: discrete-mathematics, irrational-numbers

If $x$ is a rational number and $y$ is an irrational number then $x^y$ is irrational.

I have tried to prove it,

let $x= 2$ and $y=\sqrt{2}$ then $x^y = 2^{\sqrt{2}}$,

if it is an rational number then let $x=2^{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y=\sqrt{2}$, then, $x^y= 2^{\sqrt{2} *\sqrt{2}}=4$ which is rational,

therefore $x^y$ is rational. Is it correct?

Comment: Tidy up your proof a little, but I'm pretty sure that's all there is.

Comment: You have proved (almost, if you tidy up it will be proved) that there is a rational $x$ and an irrational $y$ such that $x^y$ is **rational**. Not what your title asks for.

Comment: Not following...are you trying to prove that $2^{\sqrt 2 }$ is rational?

Comment: Simple counting shows that there must be an irrational $y$ such that $2^y$ is irrational (there are uncountably many irrationals, but only countably many rationals).

Comment: Didnvt you say you wanted to prove it was irational?

Comment: @lulu It's unclear if this user has access to that line of reasoning, as this seems to be a homework question. This is still a good indicator that their goal is to prove rather than disprove, so +1

Comment: i'm not sure, i just wanted to prove it as same way as proving if x,y are irrationals then x^y would be rationl :(

Comment: Ah, now, $x^y$ has to be rational. Please check the question.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think they're still mistaken about their goal. They may mean what they said originally but their line of reasoning did not match up in the end.

Comment: Let $x>1$ if $z \ne w $ then $2^z \ne 2^w$.  So There are uncountable many $2^z$.  They can't all be rational.

Comment: Do you know what a transcendental number is?  If so, then explicit examples can be given.

Comment: @Axoren I know, and SimpleArt has answered one case, and the other case is almost solved by the OP. But we still don't know which one it is. Like in the proof :)

Comment: Somewhat related posts can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118810/an-easy-example-of-a-non-constructive-proof-without-an-obvious-fix/1118851#1118851) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446647/irrationality-of-sqrt2-sqrt2).

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but I am trying to understand what constructive proofs are. Is the OP's question an example of a constructive proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

very close!

$\color{white}{\text{I like the try though +1}}$

Let $x=2$ and $y=\sqrt{1/2}$.

Either $2^{\sqrt{1/2}}$ is irrational, or $\left(2^{\sqrt{1/2}}\right)^{\sqrt{1/2}}$ is irrational

Comment: Classic annoying example by Hilbert? Can't remember.

Comment: @JackyChong I don't know, but I decided to play along with the OP's attempted method.

Answer (score 7):

As a concrete example of $(\text{rational})^{\text{irrational}}=\text{rational}$:
$$10^{\log_{10}3}=3$$ To see that   $\log_{10} 3$ is irrational, suppose it equaled $\frac ab$ with $a,b\in \mathbb N$.  We'd then have $$3=10^{\frac ab}\implies 3^b=10^a$$  But this contradicts Unique Factorization.

As a concrete example of $(\text{rational})^{\text{irrational}}=\text{irrational}$:  $$10^{\log_{10}\pi}=\pi$$  To see that   $\log_{10}\pi$ is irrational, suppose it equaled $\frac ab$ $a,b\in \mathbb N$.  We'd then have $$\pi=10^{\frac ab}\implies \pi^b=10^a$$  Whence $\pi $ would be a root of the equation $X^b-10^a=0$.  But $\pi$ is transcendental, hence is not the root of any polynomial with rational coefficients.

Comment: A simpler example of the former is $1^{\sqrt{2}} = 1 = \mbox{rational}$.

Comment: @Michael  True, of course...but in this sort of question, it's usual to exclude $0,1$ from the base (as the examples aren't very interesting).  For example, we have the powerful [Gelfond Schneider Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) which tells us that, if $a,b$ are algebraic with $b\notin \mathbb Q$ then $a^b$ is transcendental.  But of course this must exclude $a=0,1$.

Comment: Given the countability argument and the Gelfond Schneider theorem you mention, there are abundant examples of $(\mbox{rational})^{\mbox{irrational}}= \mbox{irrational}$. So, it surprises me that it seems difficult to come up with one concrete example.  Yours uses the transcendental nature of $\pi$ which is _not_ a basic fact (i.e. proof is advanced).  Are there simpler examples?  Of course, I suppose you can replace $\pi$ with any transcendental, but then you have to prove existence of such, which perhaps goes back to countability arguments?

Comment: [liouville's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesApproximationTheorem.html) let's you produce some "simple" transcendental numbers.  Like $\sum 10^{-n!}$.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the letters for convenience, let's show that there's a rational number $x$ such that $2^x$ is irrational. For each rational number $r,$ the curve $y=2^x$ meets the vertical line $x=r$ in just one point, and it meets the horizontal line $y=r$ in just one point. Since the set of rational numbers is countable, there are only countably many points on the curve $y=2^x$ with at least one rational coordinate. Since there are uncountably many points on the curve, there are uncountably many points with both coordinates irrational; i.e., there are uncountably many (in fact continuum many) irrational values of $x$ such that $2^x$ is also irrational. The same goes with $2$ replaced by any positive rational number different from $1.$